# How to exclude fields from django forms.Form?

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I guess this is another simple question on django forms that I am struggling to find an answer for.

Say I have the following

```
class Form1(forms.Form):
    a=forms.CharField( label=_("A"),max_length=40)
    b=forms.CharField( label=_("B"),max_length=40)

class Form2(forms.Form):
   c=forms.CharField( label=_("C"),max_length=40)
   d=forms.CharField( label=_("D"),max_length=40)

class Form3(Form1,Form2):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kw):
        Form1.__init__(self,*args, **kw)
        Form2.__init__(self,*args, **kw)

#Here I don't want to have a from Form1
# how can I exclude it so that validation does not bark??
```

I tried exclude=(a,) in Meta class defined in Form3 but does not work, form validation keeps failing form me.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why are you trying to merge the two forms? Why not just deal with the forms separately in your view?

Comment: The reason being each form that I have maintains its validation logic. The small units that I create are logical grouping of some items that I inherit and define validation in a separate forms. However, that said even for a single form I do not see how I can exclude some field as it is poossible in ModelForm?

Comment: Just to mention that I currently managed resolving this by switching the required field of field a to False in Form3.__init__ and simply not showing that in the template. But this is somewhat uggly...

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(Form3, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    del self.fields['a']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can override the field and set it to None

```
class Form3(Form1,Form2):

a = None
```

Below is the reference:
https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/8620#no1